# How do we address a person that's neither male nor female?

Tags: word-request

When addressing a man we usually say:

> Mr. Doe, it's a great pleasure to see you.

Similarly when addressing a woman we say:

> Mrs. Doe, it's great pleasure to see you.

but is there any word that can be used to address a bisexual or a transgender person ?

Comment: Please note that in English the term "bisexual" refers exclusively to sexual orientation. It isn't the same thing as being transgender.

Comment: I suggest you say "Ms. Doe ..." and not "Mrs. Doe ...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the UK it is considered incorrect to address Mr John Doe as "Mr John Doe". You address him either as "Mr Doe" or as "John".
- It is very common to move straight to first names after meeting someone. If you are meeting someone for the first time or the situation is very formal, you may wish to use their title, but you would probably only use it if you knew what it was. If Mr Doe had been knighted, he would be addressed as "Sir John", and if Ms Doe had been knighted, she would be "Dame Alexis".
- The default title for a woman is "Ms", not "Mrs". However, some women do prefer "Mrs", and some "Miss". Both offline and online forms will often ask which title is preferred.
- Some trans people use the title "Mx", pronounced "mix", but I don't think you would necessarily want to presume that this was their preferred form of address. Even with Mr and Ms, people try to find out others' preferred or correct titles (at least in the UK) - see above - rather than presuming.

From Lexico ( https://www.lexico.com/definition/Mx ): "**Mx**: A title used before a surname or full name to refer to a person of unspecified or non-binary gender".